# Does clipboard get cleared after restart on os x?

Tags: copy-paste

Sorry for silly question does OS X clipboared get clear after machine restart?

In the simple way. if i copy text and paste it, when i restart machine will it still be where on clearboard, will i still see it on paste it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. If that's a problem then get a clipboard manager.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply check that? Ok, maybe you don't have access to an OS X machine but still... I would be quite weird for the OS to save and restore such information upon reboot.

To answer

Yes, the clipboard gets cleared after every machine restart.

Comment: Well, it might be easy to check, but with all the restoring of state that OS X does nowadays (open applications, documents, etc.) it wouldn't really surprise me if it also restored the clipboard.

Comment: @Lizzan it's five years later and it's still an issue